# Speed up Python/Cython loops.

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, cython

I've trying to get a loop in python to run as fast as possible. So I've dived into NumPy and Cython. 
Here's the original Python code:

```
def calculate_bsf_u_loop(uvel,dy,dz):
   """
   Calculate barotropic stream function from zonal velocity

   uvel (t,z,y,x)
   dy   (y,x)
   dz   (t,z,y,x)

   bsf  (t,y,x)
   """

   nt = uvel.shape[0]
   nz = uvel.shape[1]
   ny = uvel.shape[2]
   nx = uvel.shape[3]

   bsf = np.zeros((nt,ny,nx))

   for jn in range(0,nt):
      for jk in range(0,nz):
         for jj in range(0,ny):
            for ji in range(0,nx):
               bsf[jn,jj,ji] = bsf[jn,jj,ji] + uvel[jn,jk,jj,ji] * dz[jn,jk,jj,ji] * dy[jj,ji] 

   return bsf
```

It's just a sum over k indices. Array sizes are nt=12, nz=75, ny=559, nx=1442, so ~725 million elements. 
That took 68 seconds. Now, I've done it in cython as

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function

## Use cpdef instead of def
## Define types for arrays
cpdef calculate_bsf_u_loop(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=4] uvel, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] dy, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=4] dz):
   """
   Calculate barotropic stream function from zonal velocity

   uvel (t,z,y,x)
   dy   (y,x)
   dz   (t,z,y,x)

   bsf  (t,y,x)
   """

   ## cdef the constants
   cdef int nt = uvel.shape[0]
   cdef int nz = uvel.shape[1]
   cdef int ny = uvel.shape[2]
   cdef int nx = uvel.shape[3]

   ## cdef loop indices
   cdef ji,jj,jk,jn

   ## cdef. Note that the cdef is followed by cython type
   ## but the np.zeros function as python (numpy) type
   cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=3] bsf = np.zeros([nt,ny,nx], dtype=np.float64)

   for jn in xrange(0,nt):
      for jk in xrange(0,nz):
         for jj in xrange(0,ny):
            for ji in xrange(0,nx):
               bsf[jn,jj,ji] += uvel[jn,jk,jj,ji] * dz[jn,jk,jj,ji] * dy[jj,ji] 

   return bsf
```

and that took 49 seconds. 
However, swapping the loop for

```
for jn in range(0,nt):
      for jk in range(0,nz):
         bsf[jn,:,:] = bsf[jn,:,:] + uvel[jn,jk,:,:] * dz[jn,jk,:,:] * dy[:,:]
```

only takes 0.29 seconds! Unfortunately, I can't do this in my full code.

Why is NumPy slicing so much faster than the Cython loop? 
I thought NumPy was fast because it is Cython under the hood. So shouldn't they be of similar speed?

As you can see, I've disabled boundary checks in cython, and I've also compiled using "fast math". However, this only gives a tiny speedup. 
Is there anyway to get a loop to be of similar speed as NumPy slicing, or is looping always slower than slicing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
/Joakim

Comment: You forgot to declare the type for the loop variables.

Comment: There is no need to declare loop variables in current Cython versions.

Comment: @jakevdp In this case not declaring them seems to let it infer the type correctly, but declaring them as `cdef ji,jj,jk,jn` without a type appears to throw it off.

Comment: Right – what I meant is that the ``cdef ji, jj, jk, jn`` line could be removed entirely and that would likely improve the execution time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Declaring the loop indices as `cdef int ji,jj,jk,jn` made all the difference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is screaming for [`numpy.einsum's`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)'s intervention, given that you are doing `elementwise-multiplication` and then `sum-reduction` on the second axis of the `4D` product array, which essenti
ally `numpy.einsum` does in a highly efficient manner. To solve your case, you can use `numpy.einsum` in two ways -

```
bsf = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl,kl->ikl',uvel,dz,dy)

bsf = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ikl',uvel,dz)*dy
```

Runtime tests & Verify outputs -

```
In [100]: # Take a (1/5)th of original input shapes
     ...: original_shape = [12,75, 559,1442]
     ...: m,n,p,q = (np.array(original_shape)/5).astype(int)
     ...: 
     ...: # Generate random arrays with given shapes
     ...: uvel = np.random.rand(m,n,p,q)
     ...: dy = np.random.rand(p,q)
     ...: dz = np.random.rand(m,n,p,q)
     ...: 

In [101]: bsf = calculate_bsf_u_loop(uvel,dy,dz)

In [102]: print(np.allclose(bsf,np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl,kl->ikl',uvel,dz,dy)))
True

In [103]: print(np.allclose(bsf,np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ikl',uvel,dz)*dy))
True

In [104]: %timeit calculate_bsf_u_loop(uvel,dy,dz)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.16 s per loop

In [105]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl,kl->ikl',uvel,dz,dy)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop

In [106]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ikl',uvel,dz)*dy
100 loops, best of 3: 3.96 ms per loo
```

Comment: That's an impressive speedup. I'll look into the einsum method. Thanks!